# How do I return data to a template with Knockout and Requirejs modules?

Tags: templates, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm having a difficult time returning data from a module using RequireJS and Knockout to populate my markup for my single page app.  Knockout can't seem to find my data binding observables.

I'm trying to keep each view in a separate js file, but I'm failing to identify where I've gone wrong. Here's what I have so far:

#### /app/app.js

```
define(function(require) {

require('simrou');

var $ = require('jQuery'),
    ko = require('knockout'),
    videoView = require('videoView');

    var init = function() {

        var viewModel = function() {
            var self = this;
            self.currentPage = ko.observable();
            self.videoView = new videoView();
        }

        var view = new viewModel();

        ko.applyBindings( view );

        _router = new Simrou({
            '/video/:id': [ view.videoView.getVideo ]
        });

        _router.start();

    };

    return {
       init: init
    };

});
```

#### /app/videoView.js

```
define(function(require) {

"use strict";

var $ = require('jQuery'),
    ko = require('knockout');

    return function() { 
        var self = this;
        self.currentPage = ko.observable( 'showVideo' );
        self.currentVideo = ko.observable();
        self.videoData = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.videoList = ko.observableArray([]);

        var getVideo = function( event, params ) {
            // ajax pseudo code
            $.ajax({});

            self.videoData( dataFromAjaxCall );
        }

        return {
            getVideo: getVideo
        };

    };

});
```

#### index.html

When I browse to /#/video/14 I receive the following error:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to parse bindings.
    Bindings value: attr: { 'data-video-id': videoData().id }
    Message: videoData is not defined
```

Here's the markup:

```
<section id="showVideo" data-bind="fadeVisible: currentPage()=='showVideo', with: $root">

    <div class="video" data-bind="attr: { 'data-video-id': videoData().id }></div>
</section>
```

Like I said, I'm trying to keep each view separated, but I would love some enlightenment on what I'm doing wrong, or if this is even possible?  Is there a better more efficient way?

Comment: It looks like you are binding the section *with* the root context, which will override the current context and set it back to the root, where videoData is within your videoView context.  Just out of curiousity, why are you binding back against your root?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean?  I thought $root would be the viewModel object and then I traverse from there.  Would the currentPage() observable have anything to do with the issue?  I assume I can't change the currentPage value from within videoView.js, correct?

Comment: Well, it depends.  I am not sure how you are handling routing or what is considered the root and what is not.  The context is very important to understand but unless you replicate the issue in jsFiddle or jsBin it is nearly impossible to help you understand what the $root is inside of that view model.

Answer (score 0):

`videoData` is a property of `$root.videoView`, not of the root model (the one you passed to `applyBindings`). It's also an `observableArray`, so `videoData()` is just a plain array and even if you get the context right, you won't be able to access its `id` property, since, being an array, it doesn't have.named properties.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I think I undestand; so, when dealing with my example, should it not be an observableArray so I can access the properties?  I thought that any returned data should be in an array.